# How to decouple a realtime game architecture

Tags: html, node.js, real-time, message-queue

I have a realtime HTML5 canvas game that runs off a node backend. Players are connected via Websocket (socket.io). The problem is sometimes I need to deploy new code (hotfixes for instance) and restart the server but I don't want to disconnect players.

My idea for this was to divide the websocket server and application server into separately deployable components and add a message queue in the middle to decouple the 2 components. That way if the application server was rebooting there would just be a short delay while the messages bunch up but nothing would be lost. Is this a good strategy? Is there an alternative?

Comment: You don't need to decouple this way : if you just make the queue persistent (or if you decouple it), you only have to make the browser reconnect when disconnected and asking for the state.

Comment: imho hotfixes shouldn't be deployed on live servers, what if a hotfix breaks some other behavior? it would be a good idea to have development servers where you would push everything you like, after positive behavior of hotfix merge it to production when scheduled. Players can be patient for 5min downtime, but eventually you will lose them if production update takes more time.

Comment: The fact you give a bounty but don't reply to comments or answers as if you didn't care is disturbing. What are you expecting ?

Comment: @MattHarrison I wasn't pressing you to accept my answer, but rather to precise what you want. This would help other users give good answers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible for websocket based applications to be restarted without the user noticing anything (that's the case for [my chat server for example](https://github.com/Canop/miaou)).

To make that possible, the solution isn't to have a websocket application isolated and never restarted. In fact this would be very optimistic (are you sure you could ensure its API is never changed ?).

A solution is

1. to ensure the client reconnects if disconnected (this is standard if you use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for websocketing)
2. to make the server ask the client its id (or session id) on client initiated reconnection
3. to persists the state of the application. This is usually done with a database. If your server has no other state than the queue between clients (which is a little unlikely) then you might look for an existing persistent queue implementation or build your own over a fast local storage (redis comes to mind)

Comment: "If your server has no other state than the queue between clients". My application doesn't actually have a queue at the moment. Part of my question is whether my problem indicates the use of a queue would be beneficial.

Comment: It's hard to know as it's very app specific. But a queue is rarely the best solution (and it's worse if you implement a queue in db). In a websocket based game platform I made, the state of the application was simply persisted and was queryable by clients. game moves were sent by websocket but if an application disconnected it just had to query the state (persisted in db server side).